# ASP.NET MVC Identity user roles management

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have been following this tutorial here http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2898/working-with-roles-in-aspnet-identity-for-mvc

I have implementing all the code and my project builds. However when I attempt to Add a user to a role, Get roles for a user or delete a user from a role I get the following error;

An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This seems to be in reference to line 47 within UserManager within my AccountController

Here is my AccountController class

```
 [Authorize]
 public class AccountController : Controller
 {
    private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

    public AccountController()
    {
    }

    public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager,  ApplicationSignInManager signInManager )
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        SignInManager = signInManager;
    }

    public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
        }
        private set 
        { 
            _signInManager = value; 
        }
    }

    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }


    // GET: /Account/Login
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }

    //
    // GET: /Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                // comment the following line to prevent login until user confirmed
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Send an email with this link
                // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }

    // POST: /Account/LogOff
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
         AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    //
    // GET: /Account/ExternalLoginFailure
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult ExternalLoginFailure()
    {
        return View();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (_userManager != null)
            {
                _userManager.Dispose();
                _userManager = null;
            }

            if (_signInManager != null)
            {
                _signInManager.Dispose();
                _signInManager = null;
            }
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Helpers
    // Used for XSRF protection when adding external logins
    private const string XsrfKey = "XsrfId";

    private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        }
    }

    private void AddErrors(IdentityResult result)
    {
        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
        }
    }

    private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
    {
        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    internal class ChallengeResult : HttpUnauthorizedResult
    {
        public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri)
            : this(provider, redirectUri, null)
        {
        }

        public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri, string  userId)
        {
            LoginProvider = provider;
            RedirectUri = redirectUri;
            UserId = userId;
        }

        public string LoginProvider { get; set; }
        public string RedirectUri { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri =  RedirectUri };
            if (UserId != null)
            {
                properties.Dictionary[XsrfKey] = UserId;
            }
            context.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(properties, LoginProvider);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
}
```

This is my ManageController

```
public class ManageController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

    public ManageController()
    {
    }

    public ManageController(ApplicationUserManager userManager,  ApplicationSignInManager signInManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        SignInManager = signInManager;
    }

    public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
        }
        private set 
        { 
            _signInManager = value; 
        }
    }

    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }

    //
    // GET: /Manage/Index
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(ManageMessageId? message)
    {
        ViewBag.StatusMessage =
            message == ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been changed."
            : message == ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been set."
            : message == ManageMessageId.SetTwoFactorSuccess ? "Your two-factor authentication provider has been set."
            : message == ManageMessageId.Error ? "An error has occurred."
            : message == ManageMessageId.AddPhoneSuccess ? "Your phone number was added."
            : message == ManageMessageId.RemovePhoneSuccess ? "Your phone number was removed."
            : "";

        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var model = new IndexViewModel
        {
            HasPassword = HasPassword(),
            PhoneNumber = await UserManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(userId),
            TwoFactor = await UserManager.GetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(userId),
            Logins = await UserManager.GetLoginsAsync(userId),
            BrowserRemembered = await AuthenticationManager.TwoFactorBrowserRememberedAsync(userId)
        };
        return View(model);
    }



    // GET: /Manage/ManageLogins
    public async Task<ActionResult> ManageLogins(ManageMessageId? message)
    {
        ViewBag.StatusMessage =
            message == ManageMessageId.RemoveLoginSuccess ? "The external login was removed."
            : message == ManageMessageId.Error ? "An error has occurred."
            : "";
        var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        if (user == null)
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
        var userLogins = await UserManager.GetLoginsAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        var otherLogins = AuthenticationManager.GetExternalAuthenticationTypes().Where(auth => userLogins.All(ul => auth.AuthenticationType != ul.LoginProvider)).ToList();
        ViewBag.ShowRemoveButton = user.PasswordHash != null || userLogins.Count > 1;
        return View(new ManageLoginsViewModel
        {
            CurrentLogins = userLogins,
            OtherLogins = otherLogins
        });
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && _userManager != null)
        {
            _userManager.Dispose();
            _userManager = null;
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Helpers
    // Used for XSRF protection when adding external logins
    private const string XsrfKey = "XsrfId";

    private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        }
    }

    private void AddErrors(IdentityResult result)
    {
        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
        }
    }

    private bool HasPassword()
    {
        var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        if (user != null)
        {
            return user.PasswordHash != null;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private bool HasPhoneNumber()
    {
        var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        if (user != null)
        {
            return user.PhoneNumber != null;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public enum ManageMessageId
    {
        AddPhoneSuccess,
        ChangePasswordSuccess,
        SetTwoFactorSuccess,
        SetPasswordSuccess,
        RemoveLoginSuccess,
        RemovePhoneSuccess,
        Error
    }

#endregion
}
}
```

Then this is my RolesController

```
 public class RolesController : Controller
 {
    ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();

    //
    // GET: /Roles/
    //[Authorize(Roles = "canEdit")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var roles = context.Roles.ToList();

        return View(roles);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Roles/Create
    //[Authorize(Roles = "canEdit")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Roles/Create
    [HttpPost]
    //[Authorize(Roles = "canEdit")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            context.Roles.Add(new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole()
            {
                Name = collection["RoleName"]
            });
            context.SaveChanges();
            ViewBag.ResultMessage = "Role created successfully !";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }

    //
    // GET: /Roles/Edit/5
    //[Authorize(Roles = "canEdit")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Edit(string roleName)
    {
        var thisRole = context.Roles.Where(r => r.Name.Equals(roleName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();

        return View(thisRole);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Roles/Edit/5
    //[Authorize(Roles = "canEdit")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole role)
    {
        try
        {
            context.Entry(role).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            context.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }

    //
    // GET: /Roles/Delete/5
    //[Authorize(Roles = "canEdit")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Delete(string RoleName)
    {
        var thisRole = context.Roles.Where(r => r.Name.Equals(RoleName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();
        context.Roles.Remove(thisRole);
        context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    //[Authorize(Roles = "canEdit")]
       [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult ManageUserRoles()
    {
        var list = context.
            Roles.OrderBy(r => r.Name).ToList().Select(rr => new SelectListItem { Value = rr.Name.ToString(), Text = rr.Name }).ToList();
        ViewBag.Roles = list;
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    //[Authorize(Roles = "canEdit")]
    public ActionResult RoleAddToUser(string UserName, string RoleName)
    {
        ApplicationUser user = context.Users.Where(u => u.UserName.Equals(UserName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();
        var account = new AccountController();
        account.UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, RoleName);

        ViewBag.ResultMessage = "Role created successfully !";

        // prepopulat roles for the view dropdown
        var list = context.Roles.OrderBy(r => r.Name).ToList().Select(rr => new SelectListItem { Value = rr.Name.ToString(), Text = rr.Name }).ToList();
        ViewBag.Roles = list;

        return View("ManageUserRoles");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    //[Authorize(Roles = "canEdit")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult GetRoles(string UserName)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(UserName))
        {
            ApplicationUser user = context.Users.Where(u => u.UserName.Equals(UserName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();
            var account = new AccountController();

            ViewBag.RolesForThisUser = account.UserManager.GetRoles(user.Id);

            // prepopulat roles for the view dropdown
            var list = context.Roles.OrderBy(r => r.Name).ToList().Select(rr => new SelectListItem { Value = rr.Name.ToString(), Text = rr.Name }).ToList();
            ViewBag.Roles = list;
        }

        return View("ManageUserRoles");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   // [Authorize(Roles = "canEdit")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult DeleteRoleForUser(string UserName, string RoleName)
    {
        var account = new AccountController();
        ApplicationUser user = context.Users.Where(u => u.UserName.Equals(UserName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();

        if (account.UserManager.IsInRole(user.Id, RoleName))
        {
            account.UserManager.RemoveFromRole(user.Id, RoleName);
            ViewBag.ResultMessage = "Role removed from this user successfully !";
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.ResultMessage = "This user doesn't belong to selected role.";
        }
        // pre populates roles for dropdown
        var list = context.Roles.OrderBy(r => r.Name).ToList().Select(rr => new SelectListItem { Value = rr.Name.ToString(), Text = rr.Name }).ToList();
        ViewBag.Roles = list;

        return View("ManageUserRoles");
    }
}
```

I believe that I have followed the sample correctly and I've checked that my code is the same as shown in the sample so I don't understand why it is not working. I tried to create a new instance of the ApplicationUserManager to see if that helps but that simply produced another error. Any help with solving this would be greatly appreciated thanks!